# Positive look ahead case

Tags: regex

I am trying to understand the positive look ahead regex. I have been following the [official website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

For a string "quit"

```
q(?=u)
```

This matches q in the string. But below does not matches anything

```
q(?=u)i
```

I can see the below explanation is given on the official website

> Let's take one more look inside, to make sure you understand the implications of the lookahead. Let's apply q(?=u)i to quit. The lookahead is now positive and is followed by another token. Again, q matches q and u matches u. Again, the match from the lookahead must be discarded, so the engine steps back from i in the string to u. The lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with i. But i cannot match u. So this match attempt fails. All remaining attempts fail as well, because there are no more q's in the string.

I want to understand why/how is this not working. Or what this second regex even implies.

What does the below mean ?

> Again, the match from the lookahead must be discarded, so the engine steps back from i in the string to u
>
> > I know lookahead is discarded and it is only used for matching(non capturing group). But what about the thing after the comma(,), I am not understanding what it is.

And this

> The lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with i. But i cannot match u.
>
> > Why i is trying to match u ??

This is not a duplicate question as I am trying to understand a special case here rather than understanding what positive look ahead is. Kindly read the full question first before marking it as duplicate

I am trying to understand how or why is this failing

```
q(?=u)i
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate question. Please see the full question first before marking it as duplicate

Comment: You're requering that q is followed by u AND the next letter is i - not possible (since it can't be both u and i.